# В программе необходимо 2 раза использовать Printwriter. Первый работает второй нет

Tags: java, запись

Пишу шаблонизатор. Есть большой шаблон в который надо вставить данные из файла, так нужно сделать столько раз, сколько строк в файле Data. Применяю Printwriter для записи в файл. Первый цикл, который записывает шапку шаблона отрабатывает исправно, второй ничего не пишет. Не могу разобраться почему. Пробовал flush(), создавать на второй цикл новый Printwriter. Не помогает. Может кто подскажет почему. Если вместо второго неработающего Printwriter цикла сделать вывод в консоль. данные выводятся корректно. т.е. дело именно в Printwriter.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ShablonCurrentLine;
        String DataCurrentLine;
        String pathReadShablon = "...\\Shablon.csv";
        String pathReadData = "...\\data.csv";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathReadShablon)); //Читаем входной шаблон
            ShablonCurrentLine = br.readLine();
            String[] titleShablonLine = ShablonCurrentLine.split(";");
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathReadData)); //Берем данные для подстановки
            while((DataCurrentLine = br1.readLine()) != null){// Построчно берем данные из Data
                String[] arrLineData = DataCurrentLine.split(","); // Разделяем строку на массив по разделителю
                String path = "C:\\..." + arrLineData[0] + ".csv";
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(path);
                for (int i = 0; i < titleShablonLine.length; i++) {
                    printWriter.print(titleShablonLine[i] + ";"); // Тут работает
                }
                printWriter.println();
                while((ShablonCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {// Построчно берем данные из шаблона
                    String[] arrLineShablon = ShablonCurrentLine.split(";");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrLineShablon.length; i++) {
                        arrLineShablon[i] = arrLineShablon[i].replaceAll("\\{\\{ station_code }}", arrLineData[1]);
                        arrLineShablon[i] = arrLineShablon[i].replaceAll("\\{\\{ station_ip_addr }}", arrLineData[2]);
                        arrLineShablon[i] = arrLineShablon[i].replaceAll("\\{\\{ camera_code }}", arrLineData[0]);
                        arrLineShablon[i] = arrLineShablon[i].replaceAll("\\{\\{ camera_ip_addr }}", arrLineData[3]);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrLineShablon.length; i++) { 
                        printWriter.print(arrLineShablon[i] + ";");//Тут запись не работает
                    }
                    printWriter.println();
                }
                printWriter.close();
            }
            br.close();
            br1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас для каждой строки используется один и тот же `BufferedReader`. Если с первой строкой данных он и сработает, то потом он делать этого не обязан - в нём могли закончиться строки для чтения ([подробный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38402126)). Ваш код будет работать, если шаблон содержит строк столько же (или больше), сколько данных вы ему передаёте

Comment: BufferedReader работает как надо, повторюсь, если сделать вывод после блока замены текста в ячейках, данные на консоль выводятся верные. Т.е. дело именно в потоке вывода, это и смущает.